# QGIS: disabling point deplacement when zooming out

Tags: qgis, rendering

I have a project in which I have multiple sets of data at the same coordinates, so I'm using the QGIS point-displacement renderer to display these points.  When zoomed in on the points this works great, and gives me just what I want:

[image]

But as I zoom out and the points become more tightly clustered, the algorithm generates ridiculous results:

[image]

I would like to tune this behavior so that, for example, QGIS would disable point displacement after a certain zoom level.  I looked at the rule-based renderer, but it doesn't appear to be possible to combine rule-based and point-displacement styles.

Can you suggest a way of resolving this behavior?